# Does LuaRocks rockspec use only file names for module sub-names?

Tags: lua, luarocks

Is it normal for LuaRocks to ignore the module name in a rockspec, using the filename instead?

```
build = {
   type = "builtin",
   modules = {

      apricot = "src/apricot.lua",
      ["apricot.stuff"] = "src/apricot/seeds.lua",
      -- `apricot.stuff` is renamed to `apricot.seeds` 
      --     when installed as a rock. 

   }
}
```

(Lua 5.1, LuaRocks 2.1.0)

Comment: I think this is bug. At least this is big surprise for me. And problem only with filename. if you write `["some.stuff"] = "src/apricot/seeds.lua"` then you get `seeds.lua` file in `some` dir. I think you should open issues on github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was a bug. I just pushed a fix:

https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/commit/0b8605f5d53a9fef54ca17bf5447132327b0ae6e

Please let me know (preferably in the bug tracker) if there are any problems with this fix. Thank you!

Comment: But note that if you publish rockspec with such ability then no one can install you module until update luarocks.